# How to insert into table in database after every 5 minutes using Real time clock module

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, sketch

I have RTC module attached to arduino mega,

to calculate time difference of minutes I am getting minute from the RTC module

and checking if passed time is greater than 5 minutes  then insert to MySQL table in database.

```
  int mint = util::getMinute();

  if (util::getMinute() - mint >= 5)

  {
    // inserting to sql database on mysql server
    INSERT_SQL = "";
    INSERT_SQL.concat("INSERT INTO arduinoSensorData.outTempLog (out_temperature) VALUES ('");
    INSERT_SQL.concat(tempInC);
    INSERT_SQL.concat("');");

    const char *mycharp = INSERT_SQL.c_str();
    delay(1000);

    if (!connected) {
      my_conn.mysql_connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password);
      connected = true;
    }
    else if (connected == true)
    {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print("Inserting : ");
      Serial.println(INSERT_SQL);
      Serial.println("Connection Successfull,inserting to database.");
      my_conn.cmd_query(mycharp);

    }
    else {
      Serial.println("Connection failed.");
    }
    mint = util::getMinute();
  }
```

the full code is [here](https://github.com/sanfx/arduinoProject/blob/WIP/webServer_Displaying_everything_v01.ino#L336)

Comment: Move `int mint = util::getMinute();` outside the loop function. Otherwise `util::getMinute() - mint` will always be `0`.

Comment: Just a tip, you didn't specify what RTC you're using, but most RTCs have an internal alarm functionality that will trigger an alert when a specific time of day is reached. This allows you to eliminate the polling from your code, and even sleep in between the 5 mins, which can greatly improve your power consumption.

Comment: Oh sweet I didn't knew that it's DS3231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out myself and used `millis` instead.

in global declaration I did:

```
unsigned long sqlInsertInterval = 300000; // the repeat interval after 5 minutes
```

then initiate timer in setup method

```
  timer = millis(); // start timer
```

followed by below changes in the loop method.

```
void loop() {
  // perform sql insert after 5 minutes
  if ((millis() - timer) > sqlInsertInterval) {
    // timed out
    timer += sqlInsertInterval;// reset timer by moving it along to the next interval

    // inserting to sql database on mysql server
    INSERT_SQL = "";
    INSERT_SQL.concat("INSERT INTO arduinoSensorData.outTempLog (out_temperature) VALUES ('");
    INSERT_SQL.concat(tempInC);
    INSERT_SQL.concat("');");

    const char *mycharp = INSERT_SQL.c_str();
    if (!connected) {
      my_conn.mysql_connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password);
      connected = true;
    }
    else if (connected == true)
    {
      Serial.print("Inserting : ");
      Serial.println(INSERT_SQL);
      Serial.println("Connection Successfull,inserting to database.");
      my_conn.cmd_query(mycharp);

    }
    else {
      Serial.println("Connection failed.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int mint = util::getMinute();

if (util::getMinute() - mint >= 5)

{
```

Well, if `mint` is `util::getMinute()` then surely `util::getMinute() - mint` will *always* be 0.

I think you meant `mint` to be `static`, or a variable in the *global scope*.

Comment: done that but I don't see database getting inserted even after making the change